# Implementing custom CALayer Subclass to draw with Core Graphics commands

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

I am implementing a UIview to contain a number of layers (about 9) to draw different elements of a graph in real time. I had previously implemented these as 9 different UIViews, and drew on them using the drawRect() function and it worked fine... but was very slow. From what I've been able to find online, it seems as if CALayers will be much faster. To make this change, I've subclassed CALayer, and only overriden the drawinContext: function. Here is the entirety of my CALayer.m file

```
#import "FFTLayer.h"
@implementation FFTLayer
@synthesize strokeColor,points,numPoints;

-(void)display{
[self drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
NSLog(@"displaying!!");
[super display];

}
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
NSLog(@"drawing in context!");
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, strokeColor);
CGContextStrokeLineSegments(ctx, points, numPoints*2);
}



@end
```

I have tried a bunch of different things. but so far, the only way that I've been able to get drawInContext: to be called is by calling it in the display() method, which seems wrong. Even when I do get drawInContext to be called, Xcode tells me that my drawing context is invalid. Here is the code that I'm using to try and tell FFTlayer to call itself.

```
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.layer addSublayer:fftLayer];
[fftLayer setPoints:fft_points];
[fftLayer drawInContext:context];
[fftLayer setNeedsDisplay];

[self  performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Even after spending a few days reading about CALAyers online, I am still pretty confused about how to properly use them, and if I'm drawing this the most efficient/correct way. In case you can't tell from the "FFTLayer" class name, I'm an audio guy, not a graphics guy :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:

I set up all of my layers in the following way

```
    //FFT Graph Layer
    fftLayer = [[FFTLayer alloc] init];
    fftLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    fftLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
    [fftLayer setNumPoints:nP];
    [fftLayer setStrokeColor:fft_strokeColor];
```

Comment: can you show how you set up your main view with all its FFTLayers? where do you create them? where do you add them to your main view layer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import "FFTlayer.h" in your view subclass?

Try to add after layer init:

```
fftLayer.delegate = fftLayer;
```